# How to call functions to a items self C#

Tags: c#, game-engine

I have a class called "Transform", and I want to make a reset function so it can reset(so call the zero function to make itself 0 vector on everything!) itself, I forgot how to make it happen(my mind just blanked!).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GameEngine
{
    public class Transform
    {

        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector4 rotation;
        public Vector3 scale;

        public static Transform Zero()
        {

            Transform trans = new Transform();
            trans.position = Vector3.New(0, 0, 0);
            trans.scale = Vector3.New(1, 1, 1);
            return trans;

        }

        public static void ResetTransform(){
        //Make itself 0!

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't assign to `this`; with your current setup, the best thing to do would be to get the result of `Zero` and assign all the values to `this`.  However, why bother calling `ResetTransformation` at all?  Just replace your instance with the result of `Zero` and let garbage collection pick up the old instance.

Comment: `ResetTransform` should probably just set everything to zeroes. Anything else is more complicated.

Comment: It smells like bad design.

Comment: Thanks, whoops, I forgot to put it in GameObject! LOL!

Answer (score 1):

```
public Transform Zero()
        {


            this.position = Vector3.New(0, 0, 0);
            this.scale = Vector3.New(1, 1, 1);
            return this;

        }
```

May be this?

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
public void ResetTransform()
{
    this.position = Vector3.New(0, 0, 0);
    this.scale = Vector3.New(1, 1, 1);
}
```

And, just wondering, do you need to set `rotation` in `Zero()`, in addition to `position` and `scale`?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with **reflection**, but that is very slow and has other disadvantages,
A redesign of your application could be a better option (reassign the variable with a new instance of this class).